# How can i adjust the volume of an audio file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have a quiz app which plays an audio file when answer is correct ..

```
var audio1 = new Audio('audio/correct.mp3');
// if answer is correct ..
audio1.play();
```

The volume of the audio is so loud .. how can i adjust it or add controls to it?

Note: jquery answers are fine too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your music is an element from the page, you can use:

```
var music = document.getElementById("myMusic");
music.volume = 0.2;
```

If it isn't, use:

```
var music = new Audio('audio/correct.mp3');
music.volume = 0.2;
```

See detailed documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp)

Comment: I didn't get this.. the audio isn't an element on the page, how get it by an ID?

Comment: `var audio1 = new Audio('audio/correct.mp3');
audio1.volume = 0.2; // 20%`

Answer (score 2):

Use the volume property which takes values in range [0, 1], as [0%, 100%] :

```js
var audio1 = new Audio('http://www.tvdsb.ca/webpages/balestrins/files/fanfare.wav'); // example audio
// if answer is correct ..
audio1.volume = 0.5; // 50%
audio1.play();
```